# What's a good way of Factory's create method in c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns, factory

Now I'm developing a c++ project. And I don't know what's a good way of c++ Factory's create method. My environment is below.

Environment:

- gcc 4.8.2 g++
- built with *std=c++11* option

I've created a Item class its instances are created by MyFactoryClass.

```
class Item {
public:
  void hoge();
private:
  int fuga;
  string foo;
};
```

In this case, what's a good way to implement *create* method? In general later method is good, but I've heard RVO in recent c++. So do both ways are no problems? And if there are better ways, I'd love to hear your examples.

```
static Item createItem(int id);
static void createItem(int id, Item& item);
```

Comment: Neither is a factory. A factory returns a pointer

Comment: See [**Boost.Functional.Factory**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/functional/factory/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: @galinette: "A factory returns a pointer"* - not necessarily; implementations of the [factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) return pointers, but that's just one type of [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) - some types of factory *don't* need to return a pointer.

Comment: What the point of a factory without polymorphism? Unless the object returned is a pointer management object behind the scenes, I don't see how this can be a factory in c++

Comment: @galinette It's useful if you have a class with members which aren't (efficiently) default-constructible and are too complex to initialize in the initialization list.

Comment: Then why not simply declaring a `Item` constructor with a `int id` parameter?

Comment: @TartanLlama : OK I see, but this smells poorly designed class. They may be practical cases I'm not aware of though.

Comment: Yeah, I can't see it being useful in this situation, but it can be in others. Another application is that you can't have a function pointer to a constructor, but you can have a function pointer to a factory class.

Comment: @galinette: there are myriad uses... for example, the factory might be part of a testing framework and tasked with creating randomised initial state, or it might be creating objects based on some input stream it owns that isn't known or exposed to the consumer of the objects, or it might be a generator for all possible combinations of some set of construction arguments etc..  You don't necessarily want the logic for these things mixed in to the Item's own constructors.

Answer (score 2):

Returning the objects is fine:

```
static Item createItem(int id);
```

You're right that RVO can help, and it usually does, but even if in some case the optimiser didn't achieve TVO, it may fall back on move semantics which can still be acceptible.  For example, given a `std::string` implementation supporting move semantics, the `foo` member will be initialised by moving rather than copy construction.

All up, returning by value is the more commonly recommended and used practice these days.  It also means the caller doesn't to construct an object beforehand, which might be problematic if there's no appropriate constructor to create an object in a not-ready-for-use state (and when you can avoid giving classes constructors that leave them in such states, it encourages good localised RAII style).

NOTE: I am trusting that you do indeed want a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) as requested in the question, and do not actually want to use the [factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to create instances of different types, albeit all derived from a common base.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create just an object then you may use following generic way which can be used for any class:

```
template<typename Class, typename... Args>
Class Create (Args&&... args)
{
  return Class(args...);  // RVO takes place here
}
```

Above is just an example, you may always modify it according to requirement. [Demo](http://ideone.com/3xG9UE).

Usage:

```
MyClass myClass = Create<MyClass>(Arg1, Arg2, Arg3);
```

However, this method is actually a wrapper upon constructor.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should return a pointer to the `Item`

```
class MyFactoryClass final
{
public:
    static Item* create( const int aId );

private:
    MyFactoryClass();
};
```

or use a shared pointer.

```
std::shared_ptr< Item > create( const int aId );
```

Comment: Why is create a member? And why non-static? Like this, you'd have to create an object before you can call `create`! Also, you should explain why you think it is better to return a pointer.

Comment: `std::shared_pointer` doesn't exist, but even then, a `std::unique_ptr` is much more idiomatic. Returning a pointer in the first place might not even be useful if there's no inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: Can you justify using dynamic allocation and `std::shared_ptr`?